# comparable type referencing

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference

can someone please explain what a functions like this

```
const Comparable & findMin() const; 
void insert ( const Comparable & x );
```

mean. Comparable is declared as template . what i specifically dont understand is how the & referencing operator works the only way this & referencing operator makes any sense to me is if used in elementary ways such as int & aref = a; to indicated that aref is a referance to a, however in the code i provided above the reference is not assigned to anything which confused me, and also why would you want to reference a whole function such as the findMin() function?

and how does something like this work

```
void insert( const Comparable & x, BinaryNode * & t ) const;
```

where they have a pointer and a reference, is this just a short way of assigning a reference to a pointer?

Comment: You have misinterpreted the `findMin()` signature : `const Comparable&` is the return type of the method (I'm assuming it's a method as I see a const qualification there).  The semantics imply that `findMin()` is expected to return a const reference to the smallest Comparable object.

Comment: 'int *&' is a reference to pointer of type int. That means you can do something like this:

void assign(int *&pI) { delete pI; pI = new int(10); }
int main() {
  int *lI = nullptr;
  assign(lI);
}

Comment: The `BinaryNode*& t` parameter implies that `insert` will also treat t as an output variable (non-const reference).  `insert` is expected to calculate a new value for t and return it directly through that variable through assignment.